# Any Simple obfuscator of HTML code generated by PHP?

Tags: php, encode

I used ioncube to successfully hide the source before. Unfortunately, it stopped working recently after modifying some other unrelated feature.

All I need is to scramble two lines of code which display the URL of a secret location to the end user.

I understand that it is not a good practice and all, but I need to do it so that someone I know can have some peace of mind.

Is there any simple way to deter a novice user from understanding the URL?

Comment: HTML is  impossible to obfuscate really - the only thing you can do is remove line breaks and spaces, and they are trivial to reinstate. Also, trying to hide a secret URL in HTML is pointless - a tool like Firebug's "Net" tab will show all requests made from a certain page in a neat list. This probably needs a different approach

Comment: Your last statement throws me off. Do you want to obfuscate the URL like http://sldn.softlayer.com/10/2008/url-obfuscation/ or actually obfuscate code that pulls a URL from somewhere?

Comment: @Pekka and @pudfox  I have a php file in the server which generates the html file. So, I guess I cannot use URL shortner.

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough for a notice user to not find / understand the URL in a source code:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

function to_entity($a) {
    return '&#x' . dechex(ord($a)) . ';';
}
$url = implode('', array_map('to_entity', str_split($url))); // encodes this url as &#x68;&#x74;&#x74;&#x70;&#x3a;…

// you can use it directly in HTML:
<a href="$url">
```

Comment: I was able to encode the URL into indecipherable form. But it does not work like the original url. So, what is the use of encoding. The browser should display the same result but the source code should display encoded URL

Comment: Note that browsers will decode the URL and display it at the bottom of the window in plain text. Also, if the user copies it, at least in my browser, it copies it after decoding it.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of javascript link obfuscation scripts out there, its trivial for even the most unskilled person to 'crack' it, but it will keep out an idiot.